# How can I delete Test Suite in Test Rail?

Tags: software-quality, testrail

I created 2 test suites in Test Rail but later on; I merged all test cases into one test suite. How to delete empty test suite?

I don't see any option/way to delete/hide that test suite.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the Test Suite. There you have a button called "Delete this test suite"

See the attached picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9dTo.png)